# how to get content from about:cache?device=disk

Tags: firefox, caching

I have a set of images which I`d like to get from my firefox cache(about:cache?device=disk), the thing is there is a pattern in the field Key that I can use to query these files that I want, but the problem is, how can I write a program to get this content?! some suggestion?! can be in python, java, c++ it doesnt really matter the language for me, just looking for some suggestion!

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a cache viewer app, built as a Firefox add-on:  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cacheviewer/

For writing your own program, the Firefox/Mozilla cache format is documented here:  http://www.pyflag.net/cgi-bin/moin.cgi/Mozilla_Cache_Format

That documentation is part of pyflag, a forensic analysis tool.  Here's the Python source code that reads the cache info:  http://www.pyflag.net/pyflag/src/FileFormats/MozCache.py

Comment: +1 : this last link looks really useful, I will try to impl and let you know if works or not! thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your .bashrc

```
export VIDEOS_REGX="\([[:space:]]AVI\)\|\(MPEG.sequence\)\|\(ASF\)\|\(ISO.Media\)\|\(Flash.Video\)"

function findvideos {
    if [[ -f videos.txt ]]; 
    then cat videos.txt; 
    else dofindvideos; 
    fi;
}

alias dofindvideos="find -exec file {} \; | grep -i '$VIDEOS_REGX' | cut -f 1 -d: | tee videos.txt"
alias playvideos="cat videos.txt | xargs vlc"
alias findimages="find | xargs file| egrep image | cut -f 1 -d: | tee images.txt"
```

Then resource it

```
$ cd 
$ source .bashrc
```

go to your cache folder and type

```
$ findvideos
```

to find all videos, or

```
$ findimages
```

to find all images.

You can view your images by installing qiv then typing at the same location :

```
$ qiv -F image.txt
```

You can view you all your videos by installing vlc then typing at the same location :

```
$ playvideos
```

Hope that helps